# IText - How can I change the text style of comments

Tags: formatting, itext, comments, bold

I noticed, that it is possible to change the text style of comments by right clicking them in Acrobat.
Right now I am coding on a c# tool that writes comments into a pdf. I use iText and i'd like to format some words in the comments in bold. Is is possible?